# Iterating over strings

Tags: string, loops, iteration, common-lisp

I have two strings of the same length which differ in exactly one character and I want a string of all the characters which are equal. So basically something like this which evaluates to a string instead of a list of characters:

```
(loop for a across "abcd"
      for b across "abce"
      when (char= a b) collect a)
```

Although performance isn't an issue here, I found it cumbersome to have a `(coerce ... 'string)` around it.

So I came up with something like

```
(loop with result = ""
      for a across "abcd"
      for b across "abce"
      when (char= a b)
        do (setf result (concatenate 'string result (string a)))
      finally (return result))
```

which does the job but looks not very elegant to me.

```
(map 'string (lambda (a b) (when (char= a b) a)) "abcd" "abce")
```

looks nicer but is not working because `NIL` is not a character when `a`and `b`are not equal.

Is there a more elegant idiom to iterate over a string and get a string back?

Comment: Maybe you want mismatch? http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mismat.htm

Comment: This gives me only the position of the mismatch not the resulting string if I read it correctly.

Comment: `map` works! See my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(loop with result = ""
      for a across "abcd"
      for b across "abce"
      when (char= a b)
        do (setf result (concatenate 'string result (string a)))
      finally (return result))
```

Repeated concatenate are not a that good idea for longer strings.

Alternatives:

**Loop into a list and coercing to a string**

```
CL-USER 3 > (loop for a across "abcd"
                  and b across "abce"
                  when (char= a b) collect a into list
                  finally (return (coerce list 'string)))
"abc"
```

**Using stream and converting it to a string**

```
CL-USER 4 > (with-output-to-string (*standard-output*)
              (loop for a across "abcd"
                    and b across "abce"
                    when (char= a b) do (write-char a)))
"abc"
```

**Using an adjustable string**

```
CL-USER 5 > (loop with string = (make-array 0
                                            :element-type 'character
                                            :adjustable t
                                            :fill-pointer 0)
                  for a across "abcd"
                  for b across "abce"
                  when (char= a b) do (vector-push-extend a string)
                  finally (return string))
"abc"
```

Comment: I have to remember that a string is an array of characters! I used the last version several times with numerical data. Thanks for showing different approaches.

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility is to use `mismatch` as in the comment of David Hodge:

```
CL-USER> (defun f(a b)
           (let ((pos (mismatch a b)))
             (concatenate 'string (subseq a 0 pos) (subseq a (1+ pos)))))
F
CL-USER> (f "abcdefg" "abcxefg")
"abcefg"
```

Comment: Something like this just came to my mind while thinking about the comment once again. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: exactly - however I was not able to post that answer this morning on the phone.

Answer (score 2):

**Use `map` to loop over multiple lists simultaneously**

```
(map 'string #'(lambda (a b) (if (char= a b) a #\Rubout)) "abce" "abcd")
```

`'string` coerces resulting list into a string. `#\Rubout` get's coerced to a zero-length string. `#\Backspace` would even delete the last character.

Comment: 1. There is no need to coerce the strings to lists: map works for any type of sequence, 2. Actually #\Rubout is a real character, which is inserted into the string, simply it is not printed for instance in the CL REPL on a terminal, but it is printed in emacs + slime (and you can verify it by computing the length of the result).

Comment: I was thinking about a character equivalent to `NIL` but did not like the side-effects @Renzo showed in his comment. Nevertheless, interesting solution!

Comment: @Renzo Thank you a lot! Now it looks more beautiful!)

Answer (score 0):

Another way (it does not assume anything about elements position)

```
    (defun only-matching (seq1 seq2)
      (remove-if-not (lambda (c) (find c seq1)) seq2))

    CL-USER> (only-matching "abcd" "abce")
    "abc"
    CL-USER> (only-matching "abdc" "abec")
    "abc"`
```

or

```
(coerce
 (intersection (coerce "abdc" 'list)
               (coerce "abec" 'list))
 'string)
```

which does not preserve order also

Note: remove-if-not is deprecated 'officially'.